# Healpix / Healpy: How can I use healpy to do SHT for a patch on the sky?

Tags: fft, healpy, spherical-coordinate

Healpix is a very useful software to do spherical analysis on a sphere. For example, we can use `map2alm` to analyze a Healpix RING ordered map and return spherical harmonics. Here the argument of `map` should be an array with `$Npix = 12*Nside^2$`. If I only want to do analysis on a patch, but not on a full-sky. Some ring-weights can be used to mask the map in Healpix. But if `Npix` is very big, actually the array of `map` will too big to be allocated in memory. Thus, how can I do the spherical harmonics transform on a sky-patch?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in `healpy` and `HEALPix`, spherical transforms are always executed full-sky.

If you are working on a small patch of sky you could use rectangular pixelization instead, see the `pixell` package at https://github.com/simonsobs/pixell, then you can use FFT transforms instead of spherical harmonics.

You can also checkout the CMB Analysis Summer School notebooks: https://github.com/jeffmcm1977/CMBAnalysis_SummerSchool/blob/master/CMB_School_Part_04.ipynb